# How can I use Vulkan on windows with an incompatible processor?

Tags: vulkan

I already have experience with Vulkan on my home computer, however I live in a dorm with a kinda old laptop.

The processor, an Intel(R) HD 4600 Graphics, is incompatible on windows with Vulkan.

I've read it might be compatible on Linux, I however have little experience of Linux and no knowledge of how I could install it on my computer/on a virtual machine.

My question is : are there any other solutions to use Vulkan with windows ?
Else, could I use a virtual machine, and which VM and OS should I use to have good performance and debugging friendliness ?

Comment: I strongly recommend switching to Linux. Linux distributions offer live environments, in which you can test things (like Vulkan support for your hardware) before installing. Since you have no previous experience, imho stick to Ubuntu - it has tons of online resources and is widely used. That being said, you may have luck with Vulkan via WSL2, using llvmpipe (/ lavapipe). A lot of people have had success with this, but it won't have the greatest of perfomance afaik. I have seen SwiftShader suggestions, but I have experience with neither. https://swiftshader.googlesource.com/SwiftShader/

Comment: What do you mean by "incompatible", I just did a quick search it seemed to suggest that a driver is available for windows, it works just fine, and it supports Vulkan. I have an ancient laptop that supports vulkan 1.1 next to the TV, btw learning linux/unix is kinda of a prerequisite if you plan to go into the computer sciences. An light intro to linux can be installing WSL (windows subsystem for linux).

Comment: Could you give such driver ? I have tested different drivers, all say I don't have a valid ICD. This intel doc (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005524/graphics.html) also says my processor isn't compatible.
I however have installed WSL and played around with Linux for a few days. Vulkan works fine there, even though it is hard to get used to...
Thanks for the suggestions !